# Is there a built-in function in Python which directly get a value of a nested dictionary through key?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested dictionary and to simplify the problem the sample dictionary below should get the value of key `2` without calling its parent key `1`.

```
dictionary = {1: {2: 4}}
print(dictionary.some_builtin_function(2))  # must print 4
```

Comment: no, there is no such thing. what would be the answer for `{1: {2: 4}, 2: {2: 5}}`?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to do that. you would call value 4 like so:
`dictionary[1][2]` or if you like you can just say `d[1][2]`

Comment: If you give an example of the problem to be solved, we could give you a solution that might be better than such a function

Answer (score 0):

The way you get a value from a nested dictionary in Python as in the example above is:
`dictionary[1][2]`
`dictionary[1]` calls the first element of the dictionary. It could really be named anything such as

`d = {"parent": {"child": 4}}`
in this example you would call, 4 by using the command:

`d["parent"]["child"]`
This is nice because it allows you to name your dictionary keys rather then just calling them by number.